# Php PDO, letting users also define the field to select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a function that selects all the data from a table, in which the user defines the field and the value. Like so:

```
public function fetch($field, $value){

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ? = ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $field);
    $query->bindValue(2, $value);

    try{

        $query->execute();


    } catch(PDOException $e){

        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $query->fetch();

}
```

I am not getting anything returned, not even an error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, or if it is even possible in PDO to let the user also choose the field of the table along with the value.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you need that?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use placeholders for *identifiers* (i.e. field names); only for *data*. You can only make a whitelist of allowed field names:

```
$allowed = array('name', 'date', 'price');
if (!in_array($field, $allowed, true)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException;
}

$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE $field = ?");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the parameters `?` in field names.

> Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. In that case you will simply want to filter and sanitize the data manually.
>   [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/938236).

To allow for user field edition directly, you could do:

```
public function fetch($field, $value){

// To avoid injection
if (!in_array($field, array('these', 'are', 'field', 'names')))
  echo "Sorry, that's not a valid field";
else
  {
  $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `" . $field . "` = ?");

  $query->bindValue(1, $value);

  try{

    $query->execute();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

    die($e->getMessage());

    }
  }

return $query->fetch();

}
```

Furthermore, I have a small function (a method actually) to do this work automatically:

```
 // Validate the cols names. 
private function setCols($TableName)
  {
  // If this script is still running, $this->Table exists in database and it's sane
  $Cols = array();
  $STH = $this->DB->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM `' . $this->Table . '`');
  foreach ($STH->fetchAll() as $Name)
    $Cols[] = $Name[0];
  $this->Columns = $Cols;
  }
```

This will find dynamically the fields for the table.

Comment: So it is not possible to let the user also define the field of the table, in anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you should whitelist the field and do some old mysql. I'll edit it to show how.